# What does "materializing" temporary table mean?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have noticed quite a few mentions of the word "materializing" when people are talking about using temporary tables in SQL Server.  Can someone expand on what it is that means? I am just trying to get a better understanding of what that means in terms of using temp tables?

Thanks!

S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "materializing" is normally used in the context of a view. When you create a clustered index on a view, you materialize the view; this means that the view's data is stored like a table on disk, and updated automatically when the tables which participate in the view get updated.

If a view is not materialized, SQL Server must compute the data in the view by performing the joins in the view definition every time a query is performed (though the results may be cached, or what-have-you).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the term "materializing" properly applies to temporary tables. The word materialized in a database context implies ["caching query results in concrete table that may be updated from the original base tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view)". Perhaps that is custom internal jargon to indicate converting the results that are in a temp table into a permanent table.